solving trace minimization problem in quadratic programming
I'd like to minimize the trace of
$P - XHP - PH^T X^T + XSX^T$
with the constraints that every entry of $X \geq 0$
here $P$ is $n$ by $n$ positive definite, $H$ is $m$ by $n$, S is $m$ by $m$ positive definite, $X$ is unknown variable $n$ by $m$
However my library can only solve quadratic programming problems in forms of $\frac{1}{2} x^T Q x - g^T x$ with constraints.
My question is whether there is a way to translate the trace minimization problem to quadratic programming problem?

You need to vectorize. Use the fact that the trace is related to the Frobenius inner product: $\operatorname{tr}(A^TB)=⟨A∣B⟩{ℝ^m⊗ℝ^n}=⟨\operatorname{vec}A∣\operatorname{vec}B⟩{ℝ^{m⋅n}}$. You can also simplify things by first decomposing $S=LL^T$ and substituting $Z=XL$.

many off-the-shelf solvers can handle your objective function directly

$
\def\t{{\large\Psi}}
\def\k{\otimes}
\def\o{{\tt1}}
\def\lR#1{\Big(#1\Big)}
\def\bR#1{\Big[#1\Big]}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\BR#1{\left[#1\right]}
\def\CR#1{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\vc#1{\op{vec}\LR{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\op{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\frob#1{\left\| #1 \right\|_F}
\def\q{\quad}      \def\qq{\qquad}
\def\qif{\q\iff\q} \def\qiq{\q\implies\q}
\def\p{\partial}   \def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\red#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\RLR#1{\red{\bR{#1}}}
\def\fracLR#1#2{\LR{\frac{#1}{#2}}}
\def\gradLR#1#2{\LR{\grad{#1}{#2}}}
$Use the Frobenius product (denoted by a colon)
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}B_{ij} \;=\; \trace{A^TB} \\
B:B &= \frob{B}^2 \qquad \{ {\sf Frobenius\;norm} \}\\
A:B &= B:A \;=\; B^T:A^T \\
A:B &= \vc{A}:\vc{B} \,=\, \vc{A}^T \vc{B} \\
\LR{PQ}:B &= P:\LR{BQ^T} \;=\; Q:\LR{P^TB} \\
}$$
to rewrite the trace
$$\eqalign{
\t = \trace{XSX^T-XHP-PH^TX^T+P} \\
}$$
as
$$\eqalign{
\t
 &= XS:X \;-\; X:\LR{HP}^T \;-\; PH^T:X \;+\; \red{I:P} \\
 &= XS:X \;-\; 2PH^T:X \;+\; \red{I:P} \\
}$$
Drop the constant $\RLR{I:P}$ term and vectorize the rest
$$\eqalign{
x &= \vc X \qiq
\t &= \LR{S\k I}x:x - \vc{2PH^T}:x \\
}$$
Renaming a few of the terms yields the desired form
$$\eqalign{
Q &= 2\LR{S\k I},\qq g = \vc{2PH^T} \\
\t
 &= \tfrac12x:Qx - g:x \\
 &= \tfrac12x^TQx - g^Tx \\
}$$
where $\k$ denotes the Kronecker product.
